# Stay on the same page after edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to follow the RailsTutorial guide, but by doing my own application instead. I have trouble with section 7, with the forms.

My controller :

```
  def update
    d = Deck.find(params[:id])
    d.title = params[:deck][:title]
    d.slug = params[:deck][:slug]
    d.category = params[:deck][:category]

    if d.save
      redirect_to deck_path(d), notice: "Deck saved successfully"
    else
      render :edit
    end

  end
```

I know it's very, very far from good code, but I will refactor it later (if you have a suggestion I'm all ears, but I use Rails 3, so I guess the strong parameters of Rails 4 are out).

The problem is when the `d.save` does not work (due to validation), with the `render :edit`.

Right now, when I enter invalid data, it tries to redirect to the `show` action, and crashes because it does not have any data to display.
If I add `@deck = d` above the `render`, it works, but the url still is the `show` action.

If my validation fail, how can I stay on the same URL and display my error messages ? Is the "change URL but render the same page" behavior accepted as valid ?

Thanks !

If you're interested in looking at the rest of the code, it's here : https://github.com/cosmo0/TeachMTG/tree/remodel-decks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually when it fails your url is not the 'show' it is the 'update' url.

Your code works.

When you submit your form, your browser sends a POST request to controller#update.

When the update fails, you tell your update action to "render :edit". What it does is it renders the :edit action inside the :update route.

The update route uses the same url as your show action :
you can check this when running 'rake routes', the only difference is that the method is POST for 'update' vs GET for 'show'

That's why you think it is the show url in the browser but actually everything works: you are on the update action that renders :edit.

(Telling your update action to 'render :edit' doesn't mean you are redirected to :edit back from :update)

Is that clear enough ?

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten to take the http verbs into consideration. I now understand this behavior. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're looking for [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) method.

Comment: Any further information on how respond_with should be used?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what is happening in the restful world.  When you do an update the URL is changing because your form is performing a `HTTP POST`.

If d.save works it redirects to your deck_path with d as the object.  If it fails it does not change the URL in the browser, but renders the same page as the `edit` action.

I'm guessing in the call for the `edit` action you have something like:

```
@deck =  Deck.find(id)
```

Your render is failing because you don't have a `@deck` variable assigned in your update.  So you can either change all of your instances of `d` to `@deck` or use your solution of setting `@deck = d`.